# The result of myString is wrong

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

/* method declaration*/
+(NSString *)setMyname:(NSString *)name Sex:(NSString *)sex Age:(int)age;

@end

@implementation Person

+(NSString *)setMyname:(NSString *)name Sex:(NSString *)sex Age:(int)age
{
    NSString* string=[NSString alloc];
    string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My name is %@ and sex is %@ and age is %d",name,sex,age];
    return string;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString* myString =[NSString new];
        myString=[Person setMyname:@"Yyx" Sex:@"Male" Age:21];
        NSLog(@"%@",myString);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result of string should be "My name is XXX".But the program didn't end friendly and the value of string is 
    `string NSString *  0x7fff7a38c830  0x00007fff7a38c830`.
And the breakpoint is at the line of `NSString* string=[NSString alloc];`.

Comment: Don't ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920568/crash-when-calling-stringwithformat) multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following:

```
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My name is %@ and sex is %@ and age is %d",name,sex,age];
```

The `stringWithFormat:` method allocates and builds the new string for you.

Then call it this way:

```
NSString* myString=[Person setMyname:@"Yyx" Sex:@"Male" Age:21];
```

Comment: How is this different to what the OP is already doing?